# tcpdump: localhost to localhost

Tags: linux, localhost, tcpdump

I write a program that send TCP packets from localhost to localhost. And I want to use tcpdump to capture the packets. But nothing is captured.
My command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo tcpdump
```

What argument shall I add? Thanks!

Comment: Not programming-related, belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo
```

#### Notes

- If you get `tcpdump: lo: No such device exists`, get the name by coping it from the output of

```
sudo tcpdump -D
```

For example, if the output is as below you need `lo0` (which is reusult `9.` here:

```
1.en0 [Up, Running]
2.p2p0 [Up, Running]
3.awdl0 [Up, Running]
4.llw0 [Up, Running]
5.utun0 [Up, Running]
6.utun1 [Up, Running]
7.utun2 [Up, Running]
8.utun3 [Up, Running]
9.lo0 [Up, Running, Loopback]
```

Comment: If you us a Mac run `sudo tcpdump -D` first to get the local interface. In my case it's: `sudo tcpdump -i 3.lo0`

Comment: Get rid of the use of `sudo`, be clear and state that this must be run as root.

Comment: Yea, it works "out of the box" without having to install special software like on windows, woot!

Comment: For Macs, this changed at some point, now the following works: `sudo tcpdump -i lo0`.

Comment: dont that pkt have ethernet hdr ? I dont see ethernet hdr contents using tcpdump ?

Comment: in order to capture on localhost port: "tcpdump -tttt -s0 -X -vv -i tcp port 1080 -w socks.cap" -> "sudo tcpdump -i lo0 -tttt -s0 -X -vv  tcp port 1080 -w socks.cap", the latter works